# Remote App Loading issue using string literal

Tags: reactjs, webpack

This is a react mono repo and the apps are remote apps inside mono-repo. above code is in shell app, I am trying to dynamically load the module using the string name from the array

The below code is not working when using dyanamic strings inside import

```
const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import(`${selectedApp.key}/Module`));

    return (
      <div>
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <LazyComponent />
        </React.Suspense>
      </div>
    );
```

What could be the reason. The strings are correct

Comment: where does your selectedApp variable get set and stored?

Comment: I  m loading it using fetch from publi/assets folder. which loads properly. then I will show a list with that data. Clicking on that list loads each react component.
The above code is executed when clicking on list data

Comment: Also this is a react mono repo and the apps are remote apps inside mono-repo. above code is in shell app, I am trying to dynamically load the module using the string name from the array